# Sorting files alphabetically and by highest to lowest

Tags: python

So I've got some high scores for a game that i created on python stored on a file. I want print the contents of the file both alphabetically and by highest to lowest score. How do I sort the file alphabetically and by score? The contents of the file is as follows:

> Name:James Score:12---Name:Alex Score:5---Name:Marley
>   Score:8---Name:Dean Score:16

I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: `open` and `read` the file, `split` the resulting string by the delimiters and save the relevant results in a dictionary/tuple or list and then use `sorted`.

Comment: Please show us the code you've written so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using pandas or anything but vanilla standard Python:

```
data = "Name:James Score:12---Name:Alex Score:5---Name:Marley Score:8---Name:Dean Score:16"
stuff1 = filter(lambda _: ":" in _, data.split('---'))
stuff2 = dict(map(lambda x: (x.split(' ')[0].split(":")[1], x.split(' ')[1].split(":")[1]), stuff1))
for name, score in sorted(stuff2.items()):
    print("{}: {}".format(name, score))

for name, score in sorted(stuff2.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]):
    print("{} - {}".format(score, name))
```